# Old AMD portable charger

Tags: battery-charging, identification, charger, charge, vintage

I found this device in my garage a few hours ago. It seems to be a very old portable charger, but I can't find what it's called or the model:

[image]

The cables plug into a small jack like so:

[image]

It uses a double-A battery to charge USB type Mini-B, old phones, and two other ports I don't recognize.

Since when did AMD manufacture portable chargers, what model is this, and where can I find it online?

Comment: It's probably not something they manufactured but instead offered as a prize or swag at a convention.

Answer (score 2):

As *JYelton* suggested, this is a promotional item offered by AMD, but not made by them.

This was usually described an "Emergency mobile phone charger". As you say, it takes 1 x AA battery (unscrew the clear lid and insert battery), and then you plug one of the supplied leads into the 3.5mm jack socket in the top, to suit your mobile phone. This was in the days when mobile phones manufacturers had many different types of proprietary charging connectors, before the standardisation on USB connectors.

Here is an example of a photo for a near-identical base product, just with a different branding on the case:

[image: emergency mobile phone charger and cables]

[Source - Maplin UK](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/universal-battery-powered-emergency-mobile-phone-charger-a74hr)

That retailer describes the product like this:

> - Provides emergency power for your mobile phone from just 1 x AA battery (supplied)
> - Duration of charging a phone depends on battery used and mobile phone being charged
> - Strong and long lasting aluminium body
> - Includes connectors for Nokia (old and new style including N & E series), Samsung, Motorola, and iPhone and iPod (please check the compatibility of the connector, not suitable for new 3G iPhones)
> - Also includes the mini USB connector suitable for charging various electronics equipment though mini USB depending on the compatibility
> - Supplied in red, silver and gold at random

As you can see, it *pre-dates* 3G iPhones!

Comment: Good find! This might be a generation or two forward from the AMD branded version. I'm not sure that flat connector in the AMD with clips is an iPod 30-pin...still looks like a Samsung/LG/HP proprietary to me. I don't miss those days of connector fragmentation in the market.

Answer (score 1):

Comment is right about the origins - it is almost certainly a freebie given away by AMD back in the 2000's. Those all look like portable electronics connectors, with the USB mini-B, barrel plug, some proprietary connector (Samsung?), and what looks like a locking PDA charger (maybe for an HP/Compaq or Palm device). The output from the charger is a TS connector (a.k.a. audio jack) that is carrying 5V + GND on the tip (T) and sleeve (S), respectively. I can see in the first photo, that there is an inductor on the PCB next to the output jack. That indicates either a buck (down) or boost (up) converter for the battery voltage to 5VDC. You might have to look at the battery configuration (parallel/series) to determine which direction the converter goes. It is likely going down from 6V (4 AA batteries) because the battery voltage will decrease from there down closer to 5V at discharge and this voltage swing might make boosting from <4.5V difficult. That converter *might* be worth salvaging for a project using a two cell LiPo battery running at 7-8V.

EDIT: I read your question too quickly and missed the fact that it uses only one AA battery (thanks to another answer for pointing that detail out). That converter is definitely a boost converter and actually quite useful for powering 5V projects from a single AA. That is actually a commercialized product called a BooSTick from Rover Development that goes for > $10...might be a good thing to cannibalize.